# Что значит оператор ::?

Tags: java, javafx, время

Изучаю JavaFX. Столкнулся с оператором :: . Объясните, пожалуйста, что он значит.
Пример:

```
public static LocalDate parse(String dateString) {
    try {
        return DATE_FORMATTER.parse(dateString, LocalDate::from);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [:: (double colon) operator in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20001427/2881286)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Это ссылка на метод](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), новая конструкция языка Java 8

Например:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("str1", "str2", "str3");
    list.forEach(System.out::print);
}
```

Произойдет следующее: интерфейс List наследуется от Iterable, у которого есть метод [`forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-).

Consumer - функциональный интерфейс, с одним методом [`accept(T t)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-), который принимает один параметр. В данном случае, consumer - метод `print` класса `System.out`, который принимает строку.

Функциональный интерфейс - интерфейс, который имеет только 1 абстрактный метод.

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, пример?

Comment: @DaysLikeThis, перенеси свой комментарий в ответ

Answer (score 0):

Оператор двойное двоеточия :: - "ссылка на метод" (Method Reference). По сути - сокращенная запись для доступа(ссылки) на метод из функционального интерфейса при использовании лямбда выражения которые появились с Java 8...

Насколько я понял это можно исползовать вызывая метод через имя класса даже если он не является статическим...
Скажем такой пример, думаю суть поймёте...

```
class MyClass{
    private static boolean method(){
        return false;
    }
    private boolean method2(){
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyClass.method());            //для статического
        Consumer<MyClass> method2 = MyClass::method2;  //для не статического
        System.out.println(method2);
    }

}
```