# Присвоение метода для экземпляра класса

Tags: java

Есть такой функциональный интерфейс:

```
public string Handler();
```

Для того, чтобы присвоить реализации этого интерфейса конктретный метод использую

```
Handler handler = SomeClass::someMethod;
```

Это будет работать только в случае, если `someMethod` является статичным, как мне сделать, чтобы я могу присвоить метод, который не является статичным?

Comment: Присваивать как метод экземпляра класса: `Handler handler = someObject::someMethod;`

Comment: @insolor, то есть, если я создаю это внутри класса, в котором определены эти методы, то нужно использовать ```this::someMethod```, я верно понял?

Comment: Да, правильно, тогда через this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть такой функциональный интерфейс:
>
> `public string Handler();`

Это не совсем похоже на функциональный интерфейс, но допустим хэндлер это он.

> Это будет работать только в случае, если  someMethod является
> статичным, как мне сделать, чтобы я могу присвоить метод, который не
> является статичным?

Не только со статичным. Но если не статик, то и экземпляр класса `SomeClass` нужен. И тут нужно чтобы количество аргументов у метода функционального интерфейса `Handler` было на один больше, чем у `someMethod`.

Можно почитать про оператор ::
[Что значит оператор ::?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715030/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80)